# Open print dialog in Silverlight after callback returns

Tags: silverlight, printing, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight app that gets a unique sequence # back from a WCF call to a db.  From there I wanted to pass that into a printing function that opens the print dialog.  But the problem is that I get a security exception if I call the open print dialog from the WCF call back (the dialog can only be opened from user click event).

I thought that perhaps a while loop in the click event but that doesn't seem to help.

Any ideas how to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

As you stated, "*the dialog can only be opened from user click event*".

All the dialog security measures are intended to protect against malicous use of Silverlight. You should not be able to circumvent it. Sorry.

Would your design allow you to request the code earlier and then have the user click a button to activate the printing?